# How do I implement a negative look-behind regular expression without using `(?<!)`?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, react-native, expo

I know about the negative look behind `(?<!)` operator, but it appears that the Javascript engine used in Expo/React-Native does not support it.  What I want is to implement the following

```
export function processEmbedded(text: string): string {
  return text.replace(/(?<!!)\[Embedded\]/gm, "![Embedded]");
}
```

What I did was a bit hacky in that I stripped and re-added.

```
export function processEmbedded(text: string): string {
  return text
    .replace(/!\[Embedded\]/gm, "[Embedded]")
    .replace(/\[Embedded\]/gm, "![Embedded]");
}
```

For my cases it does work, but I am pretty sure there's an edge case where it does not.

Comment: Does this question have much to do with TypeScript?

Comment: my examples are typescript

Comment: It doesn’t look like an exact duplicate because this question is about lookbehind assertion alternatives in typescript.

Comment: more over, it's to implement it in react-native for iOS and Android which does not support negative lookback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this work-around solution using a capture group:

```sh
export function processEmbedded(text: string): string {
  return text.replace(/(^|[^!])\[Embedded\]/gm, "$1![Embedded]");
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rqgi5s/2)

`(^|[^!])` matches start of line or a character that is not `!` in first capture group. In the replacement we put it back using `$1` back-reference.